# The news bar on news TV

Tags: word-request

There is a bar under the news on TV on which the important news is written and is moving slowly.

What is called? I thought of headline or subtitle bar, but I am not sure about them.

Answer (score 3):

It is commonly referred to as a **news ticker** and can also be called a **crawl(er)**, or a **slide(r)**. I suppose its name derives from the stock market **ticker tape** which is a continuously updated display of trading prices.

Answer (score 2):

Its called a [News Ticker](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/news-ticker). This is where all the main headlines appear, be it sports or business or current affairs, or even weather reports.

[image]

Comment: Also sometimes called a "crawl".